# create a new directory under all directories using single command : Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mkdir

Suppse if I have directories

```
dir_1/ dir_2/ dir_3/
```

How can I create a directory of same name under all these directories using a single command?

Comment: Right. The fish are in that direction. Now try to learn how to fish ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Here is one command for you:

If your want the sub dir have the same name as the parent dir:

```
for i in ./dir_*; do mkdir -p "${i}/${i}"; done
```

If you want the sub dir share the same new name.

```
for i in ./dir_*; do mkdir -p "${i}/new_dir_name"; done
```

Comment: You should probably double-quote `"$i/$i"` to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Brace Expansion

```
mkdir dir_{1..3}/newDir
```

Only work if you know the names of the dirs in advance, of course.
Doesn’t work with ’sh’ though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'dir_*' -exec mkdir {}/{} \;
```

**Test:**

```
$ ls
dir_1  dir_2  dir_3  file1  file2  file3

$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'dir_*' -exec mkdir {}/{} \;

$ ls dir_1/
dir_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `find` you could do:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -execdir mkdir -p "{}/{}" \;
```

This will create `directory/directory` if it doesn't already exist.